# Is $X(T) = A \sin(\omega_0 t + \Phi)$ mean ergodic?

Tags: integration, statistics, fourier-analysis, ergodic-theory, means

**This is an example of a tutorial but I think has not been solved properly. Please help me!**

> $X(T) = A \sin(\omega_0 t + \Phi)$
>   $A$ and $\phi$ are independent
>   $A$ is uniformly distributed over $(0,1)$
>   $\Phi$ is uniformly
>   distributed over $(0, 2\pi)$
>   Is it mean-ergodic?

It is solved as follows:

> $E[X(t)]=E[A]E[\sin(\omega_0t+\Phi)]=0$
>   $R_X(\tau)=E[X(t)X(t+\tau)]=E[A]E[\sin(\omega_0t+\Phi)\sin(\omega_0t+\omega_0\tau+\Phi)]=\frac{1}{2}E[A^2]\cos(\omega_0\tau)$
>   so it is stationary. Since its mean value is zero
>   $C_X(\tau)=\frac{1}{2}E[A^2]\cos(\omega_0\tau)$
>
> $\sigma^2_{\hat\mu_X}=\frac{E[A^2]}{2T}\{\int_{-2T}^{2T}[1-\frac{|\tau|}{2T}]\frac{\cos(\omega_0\tau)}{2}d\tau\}$

The next step is where I have problem with. I don't know whether we can substitute the fourier transform of $f$ when computing $\int_a^b f$ or are the fourier transforms computed here correct? Even I don't know the integration has been done correctly? The solution continues as follows:

> We can use the result from Fourier transform that time multiplication
>   is frequency convolution and evaluate the integral shown above.
>   $$[1-\frac{|\tau|}{2T}]\Longleftrightarrow 2T[\frac{\sin(\omega T)}{\omega T}]^2\quad and\quad\frac{\cos(\omega_0\tau)}{2}\Longleftrightarrow \frac{\pi}{2}[\delta(\omega+\omega_0)+\delta(\omega-\omega_0)]$$
>   Substituting the Fourier transforms of the triangular and the cosine functions in the equation for vairance, we obtain
>   $$\begin{align}
> \sigma^2_{\hat\mu_X}&=\frac{1}{2\pi}\frac{E[A^2]}{2T}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}2T[\frac{\sin(\omega T)}{\omega T}]^2\frac{\pi}{2}[\delta(\omega+\omega_0)+\delta(\omega-\omega_0)]d\omega\\
> &=\frac{E[A^2]}{2\pi}[\frac{\sin(\omega_0T)}{\omega_0T}]^2
> \end{align}$$
>   $T\to\infty\,,\sigma^2_{\hat\mu_X}\to 0\,,for\;\omega_0\neq 0$ Thus $X(t)$ is mean-ergodic.

**1-** I don't know if the fourier transform calculation $[1-\frac{|\tau|}{2T}]\Longleftrightarrow 2T[\frac{\sin(\omega T)}{\omega T}]^2$ is true?
**2-** I don't know whether we can compute the integral of the fourier transform of a function instead of the original function?
**3-** Regarding that multiplication in time is equivalent to the convolution in frequency space I don't know whether substituting $[1-\frac{|\tau|}{2T}]\frac{\cos(\omega_0\tau)}{2}$ in $\sigma^2_{\hat\mu_X}=\frac{E[A^2]}{2T}\{\int_{-2T}^{2T}[1-\frac{|\tau|}{2T}]\frac{\cos(\omega_0\tau)}{2}d\tau\}$ by $2T[\frac{\sin(\omega T)}{\omega T}]^2\frac{\pi}{2}[\delta(\omega+\omega_0)+\delta(\omega-\omega_0)]$ in $\sigma^2_{\hat\mu_X}=\frac{1}{2\pi}\frac{E[A^2]}{2T}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}2T[\frac{\sin(\omega T)}{\omega T}]^2\frac{\pi}{2}[\delta(\omega+\omega_0)+\delta(\omega-\omega_0)]d\omega$ is done correctly?